# Need action to happen after all UIAlertControllers dismissed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uialertcontroller

I need every single UIAlertController in my app to do a certain action whenever a user pushes a button on it (i.e. when it's dismissed). As of now, the only way I can think to do it is by individually coding this action into each of buttons handlers like this:

```
UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action)
{
    [self doSomeAction];
}];
```

There is no delegate for `UIAlertController`. How can I accomplish the same action being done every time an alert is dismissed without having to repeat the same code over and over?

Comment: Do you mean you want most alerts in your app to do the exact same thing whenever Cancel is tapped, for example? You should [edit] your question and provide more specific details or examples of what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @rmaddy Updated. Yeah I want every single alert in the app to do one specific thing when dismissed. So this has to be added for every single button action because any button push on a UIAlert dismisses it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution for this is to subclass `UIAlertController`. Then override `viewDidDisappear`. Add whatever "one specific thing" you want to happen for every alert there. Now use your custom alert controller class whenever you want this custom behavior to be done.

Comment: In the Apple docs it says not to subclass UIAlertController. You still think it will be safe?

Comment: It's perfectly safe. Just avoid any attempt to modify the UI of the alert. It will only take a few minutes to create the class. Then try it in one or two places and confirm it works as intended before committing to use it everywhere.